# IntelliJ IDEA - Unable to evaluate the expression Cannot find source class for current stack frame

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea, smali

I'm debugging android application with linked correct smali sources. I'm using newest smalidea plugin. Everything goes well, breakpoint is reachable, I can see variables but I cannot see lists.

Here's what I can see near List variable:

```
Unable to evaluate the expression Cannot find source class for current stack frame
```

Is it debugger issue or just smalidea plugin is not working properly with lists?

Answer (score 6):

Problem is fixed. I just forgot to set newest SDK in the project options

Answer (score 1):

Follow the next steps to validate which SDK is using for building the project in intelliJ

- right-click on the project
- Click on Open Module settings option
- On the left menu click on Project
- Check which SDK option is selected